# Meaning of かませるワンちゃん

Tags: meaning, manga, idioms, sports

Context: boxer A tells boxer B that the president of the gym, who is also boxer B's father, cannot come to watch boxer B's match. Boxer B doesn't have a good relationship with his father.

> Boxer A: 会長はマッチメイクでタイにいる。来れないそうだ。
>
> Boxer B: フーン…　かませるワンちゃん見つかったな親父…　ハハ！

What is the meaning of かませるワンちゃん? I think the verb is 噛む. I understand the literal meaning, but not the actual one. Is it an idiomatic expression? Something like `a dog to give orders to` or `a dog that talks for him`? My translation attempt:

> Boxer A: The president is in Thailand to organize a match. It looks
>   like he won't come.
>
> Boxer B: Ha! My father found a dog that talks for him. Ah ah!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe rather than 噛む in this case could be 噛ませる (which is a verb itself) or the potential form of 噛ます？ They both mean "to force something into someone's mouth". Not sure but that sounds a better
 match for this situation than the meanings of 噛む.

Comment: 「かませ[犬]{いぬ}」のことですかね？？

Comment: (P.S. https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/かませ犬 ・
 https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/44586/meaning/m0u/ ... 違ったらすいません)

Comment: I thought Boxer B was referring to Boxer A, but maybe he's not. Previously, the president has said 「ライトフライの世界戦の相手でお手頃のが見つかりそうでな…　まだしばらくタイにいる」. Do you think it could be related to this?

Comment: @Marco  To match my answer more in the sentence, I need to know who the ライトフライの世界線の相手 is.

Comment: @kimiTanaka Unfortunately no further details are provided in the manga. Don't worry, your answer is already good as it is.

Comment: Obviously 噛ませるワンちゃん refers to 噛ませ犬, but I don't quite understand why 会長が来れない means "my father found a weak opponent of a boxing match." This is heavily context-dependent, but are you sure they are talking about finding an opponent?

Comment: @naruto I think so. The president is in Thailand for matchmaking, he found a 噛ませ犬 so he had to stay there to define the match details, at least this is what I understood.

Comment: @Marco Fine, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "噛ませるワンちゃん" implies "噛ませ犬". I don’t know a dogfight system though, I guess the word comes from them. In a combat sport like boxing, it is not uncommon that a match-maker chooses the opponent which their boxer definitely wins in order to get his boxer confidence.

It is very similar to ”underdog” in English though, while the underdog is used when a team always lost regardless of making an effort, かませ犬 himself often doesn't intend to win from the beginning.

Edit:1

Sometimes 噛ませ犬 makes an upset in a boxing match. Say, a match-maker prepares a world championship between ex-champion which seems already passed his best time and an undefeated-prospect for the future champion. An ex-champion seemed 噛ませ犬 by a matchmaker though, he showed his pride and won the match. So, 噛ませ犬 has a broader usage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So basically it refers to a weak boxer that can be easily defeated by the matchmaker's boxer, and he accepts to loose from the beginning, right?

Comment: Yes. At least a match-maker expects that the opponents is supposed to lose the game. However, as you say world-championship like “世界戦” in the comment, it might fit “underdog” in the context. Their competences might not be so different just because the opponent has been losing for a few games in a row.